# SQL Query to achieve following output

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having following tables as provided in given image below.
Please write a sql query to to achieve required output.

[image]

Write a Single Select Statement to achieve this output.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query...

```
Select m.Id,Name=Case
CID
When 1 Then (Select t1.Name from Table1 t1 Where m.Id=t1.Id)
When 2 Then (Select t2.Name from Table2 t2 Where m.Id=t2.Id)
When 3 Then (Select t3.Name from Table3 t3 Where m.Id=t3.Id)
When 4 Then (Select t4.Name from Table4 t4 Where m.Id=t4.Id)
END
from MasterTable m
```

Comment: thank you so much it works...:-) Can we pass these CID's dynamically in Case statement instead of passing statically?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in a stored procedure and create your dynamic query.